# Java Class Constructor changes input parameter - MiniMax

Tags: java, constructor

I am working on MiniMax code for Connect 4. Basically I have a  class SimpleMiniMax which has a method minimax (takes input of grid ) which is supposed to return an instance of Class Move. The method minimax makes call to method maxMove which takes input of grid (same as first method call). Here the maxMove method generates Moves for AI and then runs mimMove. The issue is when it generates Move for AI it passes current Grid and gets the Move back.But in this process it changes current Grid as well. So when it goes through all the possibilities it keeps on adding AI moves on to same Grid. So after all 7 possibilities (Connect 4 grid is standard 6 row 7 column) AI fills up 7 positions and obviously wins.

I tried copying the input parameter into a local variable and passing that but the values still flow through. I had understanding that the parameters passed to Java methods are passed by value (Read only if you will). I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

here is the brief code.

```
public class SimpleMiniMax {

private static Boolean noMoreMoves = false;


public Move minimax(int[][] gridCopy_minimax){
    Move nextMove = null;
    noMoreMoves = false;
    return maxMove(gridCopy_minimax, 1);

}

private Move maxMove(int[][] gridCopy_max, int depth){
    int gameValue = 0;

    Move maxMove = null,
            tempMove = null,
            thisMove = null;

    if(depth==0 || noMoreMoves){
        return null;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            try {
                thisMove = new Move(gridCopy_max, i, Grid.getAI());
// Issue here---
// After this call the value of gridCopy_max carries the Ai move so when its   
// called for next loop run it builds from there on.
                tempMove = minMove(thisMove.newGrid, depth-1 );
                if(tempMove==null) tempMove = thisMove;

                if (maxMove==null && tempMove != null) maxMove = tempMove;

                if(tempMove != null && tempMove.moveValue >= maxMove.moveValue ){
                    maxMove = tempMove;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                if(i==6){
                    noMoreMoves = true;
                    break;  
                }


            }


        }
    }

    return maxMove;

}

Class Move
public class Move {
public int[][] newGrid = new int[6][7];
public int moveX = 9,
        moveY,
        moveValue;




public Move(int[][] CurrGrid, int y, int player_in) throws Exception{



    newGrid = CurrGrid;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
        if(CurrGrid[i][y] != 0){
            moveX = i-1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i<0){
        throw new Exception("No More Moves");
    }

    if(moveX==9){
        moveX = 5;
    }

    moveY = y;
    newGrid[moveX][y] = player_in;

    this.moveValue(player_in);

    System.out.println("Generating Move" + player_in + "|" + moveX + "|" + moveY);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you copied to the local variable is a pointer to the array. For reference arguments, Java passes, by value, the reference itself, which is either null or a pointer to the object.

I suggest copying the contents of the array referenced by the argument into a locally created array before modifying it.

Comment: I tried creating local copy like this --> int[][] gridCopy = gridCopy_min; and passed it to the method. Do you mean I need to copy it element by element?

Comment: Yes, you need to copy the contents. Not necessarily element-by-element yourself - see `java.util.Arrays` for some useful methods. All you did was to copy the reference that points to the array, not the array.

Comment: many Thanks! I created a small code to test this and it does work ! Learning new things everyday !